# selenium webdriver (c#) ExpectedConditions - How to get a handle if an element does not exist?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Using c# and selenium webdriver, I'm able to get a handle of whether or not an element exists by using the following code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(login))));
```

But how can I check the opposite?  i.e that an element does not exist?

Comment: Think about it - how can you verify something that doesn't exist? The only check you can do is to check for its existence, wait for the timeout and then _assume_ that it is absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Selenium doesn't have an `Exists` property, which would be very useful.  Instead, Selenium throws an exception if, for example, an element is not present.  This has made testing to ensure an element is not present on a web page a little interesting to handle.

I took the approach of seeing if an element is `Displayed`, and wrapping that in a try-catch:

```
bool displayed = false;
try
{
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(ByLocator));
    displayed = driver.FindElement(ByLocator).Displayed;
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: The other option, if blindly catching exceptions rubs you up the wrong way, is to use `.FindElements` which will return an empty list if there are no elements matching that locator.

Comment: You could do that, but then you need to test the `Count` of the list.  I thought about that approach, but decided trapping exceptions was a little less work.

Comment: Not necessarily the `Count` but rather `.Any` so that LINQ can easily tell you "do I have any items" rather than "do I have X number of items". So `.FindElements(selector).Any()`...but yeah, I know what you mean, not much difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Displayed" is a bad idea, as "displayed" means "is visible". If element will have "display: none;" css style, it will be marked as non-existed. **But this element still exists! Just not visible!**

Better to use function like this:

```
public bool IsExist()
{
    if (element == null || element.Size.Width < 1)
    {
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you see its checking for null object and for element width. 
I believe that more likely element will be not displayed(not visible) than it will have width <1 =)